# trigger event globally in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am binding a custom event on `div`. I want to trigger that event globally without specifying target element.

**edit:**
Right now I am binding my custom `event` with `div` but it can be bind with any of tag. So instead of trigger event with selector. I want to trigger it globally.

I want to avoid repetition like

$('p').trigger('customevent')
$('div').trigger('customevent')

```
var g= document.getElementsByTagName('div')
$('div').bind('alwaysListen',function(){
   $(this).hide()
});

$('a').click(function(){    
   $.event.trigger('alwaysListen');
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fa1s9e0s/).

Comment: I think you trying to fix something the wrong way. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: You cannot trigger events "globally". Events need a target. You can trigger events on `document` or `window`, but then the `<div>` will not see them.

Comment: The only thing you *could* do would be to trigger the event on each and every element, but you really *shouldn't*.

Comment: Why you defined var g?  you haven't used it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event will be bubbling [across DOM nodes up and down anyway](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html), so in some way it;s anyway global; 
That's why you can do :

```
$(document).on('alwaysListen', function(){    
   //do stuff
});
```

Here is a link to you updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fa1s9e0s/7/